# how to select first two box classes by using pseudo-element

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

There are total four box classes, am not able to select first two elements with box class

```
<div class="quiz-options">
                            <div class="row just">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="1" class="box"><!-- <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o option-r" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 18px"></i> -->
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">A</span> -->Comuter</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="2" class="box">
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">B</span> -->Vechile</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="3" class="box">
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">C</span> -->Motor</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="4" class="box">
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">D</span> -->None</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: You want <input> element, no <div>

Comment: there are total 4 boxes in quiz option, i was trying two add background color for first two boxes only..

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
.row.just div > .box:first-child,
.row.just div > .box:nth-child(2) {
    /** css code **/
}
```

Or if you want to select with JavaScript - jQuery:

```
$(".row.just div > .box:first-child")
$(".row.just div > .box:nth-child(2)") 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use nth-child in this case

```
 .box:nth-child(1),
 .box:nth-child(2)
 {
 background-color:#fff;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child(n)` selector for it. The `:nth-child(n)` should be applied to **parent** of `.box` element as there are four children of  `.row` element.

```css
.row div:nth-child(1) .box,.row div:nth-child(2) .box{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-options">
                            <div class="row just">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="1" class="box"><!-- <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o option-r" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 18px"></i> -->
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">A</span> -->Comuter</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="2" class="box">
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">B</span> -->Vechile</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="3" class="box">
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">C</span> -->Motor</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <div tabindex="4" class="box">
                                        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">D</span> -->None</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row.just > div:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-options">
  <div class="row just">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <div tabindex="1" class="box">
        <!-- <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o option-r" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 18px"></i> -->
        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">A</span> -->Comuter</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <div tabindex="2" class="box">
        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">B</span> -->Vechile</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <div tabindex="3" class="box">
        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">C</span> -->Motor</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <div tabindex="4" class="box">
        <!-- <span class="quiz-opt">D</span> -->None</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```